# Change the landing page for when a website is stopped in windows azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to to change the landing page for a stopped website in windows azure? I've attached the image for a clearer idea. Thank you.
[Stopped web site in windows azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Eep.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the answer here is no. If the website is stopped then it is not accepting requests, which means this page you are seeing is being served up by the Azure Web App Service directly. There isn't a way to then indicate the site should use a custom page when stopped.

If you really want a different page to show up you may want to look at something like Azure Traffic Manager which can cause traffic to flow to a different site when it sees the target site is down; however, realize that is a DNS based service so it won't be immediate.

Comment: Correct, it's not possible to change the landing page.